# SQL min function for subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, in-subquery

I want to find company name which has the lowest amount of trip_no

how do I find the lowest amount of trip_no

```
select t1.Id_comp, company.name,
count(t1.trip_no)
from trip t1
    inner join company on t1.ID_comp=Company.ID_comp
group by t1.Id_comp, company.name
having count(t1.trip_no) = (select min((select t2.ID_comp ,count(t2.trip_no)
                                            from trip t2 
                                            group by t2.ID_comp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Id_comp ORDER BY trip_no DESC) AS r 
FROM trip INNER JOIN company on trip.ID_comp=Company.ID_comp) sub
WHERE r = 1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 